# C3198, and A1266 Replacement

Tags: transistors

I have these foreign Japanese transistors, and was looking for their equivalent in the 2NXXXX series.  What would be a good replacement? This is the first time I have seen any of the transistors any other information needed that I put just comment and tell me.

Comment: Those are Japanese partial part numbers, 2SC3198 and 2SA1266 would be the full part numbers.  C3198 is NPN, general purpose, in a TO92 package, ECB pinout.  A1266 is PNP, 80V, also TO92 package, also ECB pinout.   Common 2N transistors usually have EBC pinout (that requires some wire-twisting when replacing).   NTE (<nteinc.com>) suggests NTE85 to replace C3198, and NTE290A to replace A1266.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by  Whit3rd is the answer to the question I was looking for.

> Those are Japanese partial part numbers, 2SC3198 and 2SA1266 would be the full part numbers. C3198 is NPN, general purpose, in a TO92 package, ECB pinout. A1266 is PNP, 80V, also TO92 package, also ECB pinout. Common 2N transistors usually have EBC pinout (that requires some wire-twisting when replacing). NTE () suggests NTE85 to replace C3198, and NTE290A to replace A1266. – Whit3rd